# Group by multi select parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, parameters, multi-select, ssrs-tablix

I have a multi select parameter in SSRS report. I for each option selected there are records in table.

I wish to show a table which is grouped by "option" selected in multi select, as shown in image. I am using =Parameters!IncidentNo.Label(0) in first column but its picking up first record always.

Grouping is not a problem but first data should be correctly loaded in report.

Records highlighted with red belongs to second option selected.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By useing hte expression

```
 =Parameters!IncidentNo.Label(0)
```

You are telling SSRS that you want to show the first (index 0) entry from the list of parameter labels from the IncidentNo parameter.

You need to simply choose the incident number field. If you click in the text box you should get a drop down to choose from, if not just edit the expression to something similar to this

```
=Fields!MyIncidentNoField.Value
```

Comment: This is a parameter and not present in result dataset to read like =Fields!MyIncidentNoField.Value Now I have two options, either read the corresponding parameter value. e.g. option IR-002-291 results 5th row onwards ni given pic but its repeating Label(0) only.

first option in multiselect value resulted in first four records in result dataset, second option selected resulted in 5th record onwards in resultset. Is there any way to show option label value to display in resultset?

Comment: You need to include the incident number in your result set otherwise there is no way to tell which records relate to which parameter value.